# Condition Search and replace C#

Tags: c#, search, replace, conditional-statements

Hello and thanks for the attention.

Edit: im not a programmer, and I have almost no idea of C# or any other language so, sorry for the question, i've been looking for a solution but nothing works. Thanks anyways you downvoted my question.

To the point, I got this code:

```
using System;
using VisualWebRipper.Internal.SimpleHtmlParser;
using VisualWebRipper;
public class Script
{

    public static string TransformContent(WrContentTransformationArguments args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Place your transformation code here.
            //This example just returns the input data

            return args.Content;
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            //Place error handling here
            args.WriteDebug("Custom script error: " + exp.Message);
            return "Custom script error";
        }
    }
}
```

I need to do a Condition with C# which let me find in **args.Content* (who contains a variable string) the string *"No se exige"*, and if the Find match it change the string value to a digit (0) and return it. If not nothing changes.

So, I just need to search and replace a string into a digit if it match with the string "No se exige".

Many thanks for the try hard reading my english, hope you can help me :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't expect this site to do your homework for you without showing any effort...

Comment: Couple of examples would make the description thousand times clearer

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - please read it, for the sake of us and our fellow SO brothers.

Comment: I feel sorry, but im not a programmer, thats why im asking : (

Comment: If you aren't a programmer, then why are you writing code?

Comment: For work, yes im doing this off work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method:

```
args.Content = args.Content.Replace("No se exige", "0");
```

Comment: presumeably they downvoted because they want the user to try something himself and actually learn something but youre right in that it answers the question so i upvoted to cancel it out